# "No such file or directory" error on existing file?

Tags: shell, zsh, ls, symlink

I have an issue with a binary(?) that simultaneously seems to exist and not exist.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/vue
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  admin  73 Jul 14 15:31 /usr/local/bin/vue -> ../../../Users/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue
$ /usr/local/bin/vue
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/vue
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Most probably you deleted the target file after linking it with `/usr/local/bin/vue`

Comment: If you see this when running a shell script, it might be because of `\r\n` line endings that can be fixed by `dos2unix`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193054/6517383

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find that `/Users/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue` does not exist.

The symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/vue` exists, so you can see it with `ls -l`. But the target does not, so there's not really any file there.

You can confirm this with either of these two commands

```
ls -lL /usr/local/bin/vue
ls -l /usr/local/bin/../../../Users/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue
```

The first tells `ls` to give you information about the *target* of the link rather than the link itself (`-L`). The second looks directly at the target.